# How to join 1 table with 2 foreign at the same table using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to join 1 table with 2 foreign key at the same table in Codeigniter. I try to do query using SQL it work well but when integrate in Codeigniter with DataTable it won't work. The following codeigniter SQL code are located below.

The query must be like this, this work well:

```
SELECT * FROM kf_emails
JOIN kf_emailserver AS A
ON kf_emails.kf_email_incomingserver = A.kf_emailserver_id
JOIN kf_emailserver AS B
ON kf_emails.kf_email_incomingserver = B.kf_emailserver_id
ORDER BY kf_email_id DESC;
```

This is in codeigniter

view.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css') ?>"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css') ?>"/>
        <style>
            .dataTables_wrapper {
                min-height: 500px
            }

            .dataTables_processing {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                width: 100%; 
                margin-left: -50%;
                margin-top: -25px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                color:grey;
            }
            body{
                padding: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2 style="margin-top:0px">Kf_emails List</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <div style="margin-top: 4px"  id="message">
                    <?php echo $this->session->userdata('message') <> '' ? $this->session->userdata('message') : ''; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                <?php echo anchor(site_url('kf_emails/create'), 'Create', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
        <?php echo anchor(site_url('kf_emails/excel'), 'Excel', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="80px">No</th>
            <th>Kf Email Emailaddress</th>
            <th>Kf Email Incomingserver</th>
            <th>Kf Email Outgoingserver</th>
            <th>Kf Email Emailusername</th>
            <th>Kf Email Emailpassword</th>
            <th>Kf Email Status</th>
            <th width="200px">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js') ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function(oSettings)
                {
                    return {
                        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
                        "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
                        "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
                        "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
                        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
                        "iPage": Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
                        "iTotalPages": Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
                    };
                };

                var t = $("#mytable").dataTable({
                    initComplete: function() {
                        var api = this.api();
                        $('#mytable_filter input')
                                .off('.DT')
                                .on('keyup.DT', function(e) {
                                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                        api.search(this.value).draw();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    oLanguage: {
                        sProcessing: "loading..."
                    },
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    ajax: {"url": "kf_emails/json", "type": "POST"},
                    columns: [
                        {
                            "data": "kf_email_id",
                            "orderable": false
                        },{"data": "kf_email_emailaddress"},{"data": "kf_emailserver_serveraddress"},{"data": "kf_emailserver_serveraddress"},{"data": "kf_email_emailusername"},{"data": "kf_email_emailpassword"},{"data": "kf_email_status"},
                        {
                            "data" : "action",
                            "orderable": false,
                            "className" : "text-center"
                        }
                    ],
                    order: [[0, 'desc']],
                    rowCallback: function(row, data, iDisplayIndex) {
                        var info = this.fnPagingInfo();
                        var page = info.iPage;
                        var length = info.iLength;
                        var index = page * length + (iDisplayIndex + 1);
                        $('td:eq(0)', row).html(index);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

model

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Kf_emails_model extends CI_Model
{

    public $table = 'kf_emails';
    public $id = 'kf_email_id';
    public $order = 'DESC';

    public $table1 = 'kf_emailserver';
    public $id1 = 'kf_emailserver_id';
    public $order1 = 'DESC';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // datatables
    function json() {
        $this->datatables->select('kf_email_id,kf_email_emailaddress,kf_emailserver_serveraddress,kf_emailserver_serveraddress,kf_email_emailusername,kf_email_emailpassword,kf_email_status');
        $this->datatables->from('kf_emails');
        //add this line for join
        $this->datatables->join('kf_emailserver AS A', 'kf_emails.kf_email_incomingserver = kf_emailserver.kf_emailserver_id');
        $this->datatables->join('kf_emailserver AS B', 'kf_emails.kf_email_outgoingserver = kf_emailserver.kf_emailserver_id');
        //$this->datatables->join('table2', 'kf_emails.field = table2.field');
        $this->datatables->add_column('action', anchor(site_url('kf_emails/read/$1'),'Read')." | ".anchor(site_url('kf_emails/update/$1'),'Update')." | ".anchor(site_url('kf_emails/delete/$1'),'Delete','onclick="javasciprt: return confirm(\'Are You Sure ?\')"'), 'kf_email_id');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
    }

    // get all
    function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }

    // get data by id
    function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
    }

    // get total rows
    function total_rows($q = NULL) {
        $this->db->like('kf_email_id', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_emailaddress', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_incomingserver', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_outgoingserver', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_emailusername', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_emailpassword', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_status', $q);
    $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    // get data with limit and search
    function get_limit_data($limit, $start = 0, $q = NULL) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        $this->db->like('kf_email_id', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_emailaddress', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_incomingserver', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_outgoingserver', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_emailusername', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_emailpassword', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('kf_email_status', $q);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }

    // insert data
    function insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }

    // update data
    function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    // delete data
    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**Controller**

```
 public function index() {

$join_str[0] = array('table' => 'category',
                    'join_table_id' => 'category.category_id',
                    'from_table_id' => 'product.category_id',
                    "join_type" => 'left'
                );
                $condition_array = array();
                $data = 'product.*,category.category_name';
                $result_product_details = $this->common->select_data_by_condition('product', $condition_array, $data, $sortby = '', $orderby = '', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str, $groupby = '');
}
```

**Model**

```
function select_data_by_condition($tablename, $condition_array = array(), $data = '*', $sortby = '', $orderby = '', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str = array()) {

        $this->db->select($data);
        $this->db->from($tablename);

        //if join_str array is not empty then implement the join query
        if (!empty($join_str)) {
            foreach ($join_str as $join) {
                if (!isset($join['join_type'])) {
                    $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id']);
                } else {
                    $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id'], $join['join_type']);
                }
            }
        }

        //condition array pass to where condition
        $this->db->where($condition_array);


        //Setting Limit for Paging
        if ($limit != '' && $offset == 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        } else if ($limit != '' && $offset != 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }

        //order by query
        if ($sortby != '' && $orderby != '') {
            $this->db->order_by($sortby, $orderby);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        //if limit is empty then returns total count
        if ($limit == '') {
            $query->num_rows();
        }
        //if limit is not empty then return result array
        log_message('debug', 'fetching data result:' . $this->db->last_query());
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```